# (2,1)-limits vs 2-limits of categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

In the section 1 of [these notes](https://topological-modular-forms.github.io/PDFs/constructions-with-categories.pdf#section.1), Emily de Oliveira Santos gives an explicit construction of most usual (co)limits in the 1-category of categories. In the next section she affirms that the same constructions also satisfy the universal properties of (co)limits in the 2-category of categories.

**What about (2,1)-limits and colimits of categories? Do they also coincide with the respective (co)limits in the 1-category of categories?**

Moreover, is there a simple construction of filtered colimits / cofiltered limits of categories?